# Can I connect a router and a bridge to a server without needing two NIC's

Tags: backup, remote, bridge, router

Excuse my ignorance as I am entirely new to this.
We have an exchange server 2008 connected to a router and have in the past remotely backed up our files off site using an ADSL broadband connection to the remote site.

Our data requirements continually exceed our data cap from our ISP we wish to connect to our remote host using a wireless network bridge.

Is it possible to connect both to the switch, the existing router(ADSL) giving internet access and the new wireless router configured as a bridge to provide the backup path. 
The backup software doesn't appear to have a setting pointing to an alternative gateway only the Ip address of the backup location.

Do I need two Nic's or is there an alternative.

As previously stated I am relatively inexperienced so please be gentle if I have asked a silly question

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear exactly on your set-up but I'm presuming that could add a static route on the server for the backup IP address that forces the traffic to use the alternative gateway instead of the default.